# SuperResolution nextFrame bug

Tags: c++, opencv

In the superresolution (gpu/super_resolution.cpp) sample (built with vc11 compiler) the the following line:

//Ptr superRes;

```
superRes->nextFrame(result);
```

results the following error error (tried with multipe test videos):

http://i.imgbox.com/abwNaL3z.jpg

and if I change the optical flow method to simple, it takes forever to run (stopped 30 min with an i7 2600k)

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

The BTV SuperResolution algorithm was oriented for small input videos. And it use a lot of memory for inner buffers. Your video has large resolution [768 x 576] and you upscale it with factor 4. Try to reduce scale factor, temporal radius or input resolution (for example upscale only a part of frame).

Comment: The 6.5Gb of memory use seems a little too much to me, but t works with ultra low resolution.